# Send message on multiple lines

Tags: python, discord, newline, sendmessage

Im trying to get my tool to send a message automatically in discord servers, However, My message is more than one line. I tried using putting it all in one line and using '\n' to get a new line. But that doesn't work. It only reads the bottom message of the entire message. I have the message put in a message.txt so the user doesn't have to edit the programme.
Here's the definition of the function + the send message function, LMK if you need anything else

#Message

```
    def loadmessages():
lines = []
with open('messages.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
#had trouble formatting code
```

#Send message

```
def send_messages(message_data,):
connection = get_connection()
m=dumps(message_data)
with open("Channel ID's.txt","r") as f:
    ChannelIDs = f.read().split("\n")
for channel in ChannelIDs:
    send_message(connection, channel,m,)
    sleep(5)
    repeat()
```

Comment: Can you make sure your code is formatted correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can always read a text of a file into variable. For example:

```
message = ""

with open('messages.txt', 'r+') as f:

  for line in f.readlines():
        message+=line
```